# Trying to use material-ui icons but getting white screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am trying to use material-ui icons, but when I use them, they show a white screen.
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm install @material-ui/icons
i have installed this material ui website
how can we solve this

i tried installing core icons from material ui still same error

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use React (since you wrote it in the tags), you should, after installing the dependencies (as you have already done), import the component you want as follows:

```
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core'; //importing material ui component
```

and then insert the component into the project:

```
<Button> Press me </Button>
```

The following is a complete guide:
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-implement-material-ui-in-react/